# How do I update installed PhoneGap/Cordova Plugins?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

When using PhoneGap/Cordova plugins like they are installed like this:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera
cordova plugin add https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin.git
```

I can update PhoneGap/Cordova like this:

```
sudo npm update -g phonegap
sudo npm update -g cordova
```

But I cannot find how I update the installed plugins when there is a new version or even a new commit in the repository.

**How do I update the installed plugins?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the plugin first:

```
cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.camera
```

Then add it back to your project:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera
```

See [docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface) for more details and advanced options. In addition to the standard CLI utility, you can add plugins using [plugman](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/plugin_ref_plugman.md.html#Using%20Plugman%20to%20Manage%20Plugins).

Comment: For projects that have a lot of plugins, I like the route of writing a shell script that removes and adds them. This way one can update all the project's plugins with one command (being certain, of course, to read all the changes and handle any breakages in the app due to updated plugins).

Answer (score 0):

You can update plugins the same way you install them - just run `cordova plugin add` again for every plugin you wish to update.

There is no information about updating plugins form cli in documentation, so i guess this is only option.

Comment: This option gives an error because the plugin is already installed.

Comment: Try `cordova plugin rm` first then ;)